# How can I find Scroll Bar Code; How does it get created?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, vba, scrollbar

There is a datagridview in my application where a scroll bar is being created at runtime. I need to make some modification to the scroll bar (need to make it shorter to position a page-up page-down bottom on top and bottom of the bar)

having a difficult time finding the sourcecode where the scroll bar gets created. I went into debugging mode to find that out however it is like a ghost and it shows up when gridview populates.

Any Help or information is appreciated.

Comment: I would guess that the scrollbars are created as part of the main Win32 API. The .NET controls are wrappers around those. So you won't really find .NET code that create the scrollbars anywhere. Take a look at the reference source for `ScrollableControl` http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ScrollableControl.cs

Comment: It would probably be better to find another PgUp/PgDn idiom.  Some scrollbar stuff is is in the DGV, some in Control and most in Native Win32 code.  You could try overriding Wndproc to display a set of your own size, but that means taking over *all* the scroll related code.

Answer (score 1):

The scroll bars are part of the DataGridview. the only way to interact with them is through the associated properties of the datagridview itself: `AutoScrollOffset`, `HorizontalScrollBar`, `HorizontalScrollingOffset`, `ScrollBars`, `VerticalScrollBar`, `VerticalScrollingOffset`

Here is the MSDN for the DataGridView control:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx